# Custom URL Extensions with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

any htaccess code which helps me for custom URL extensions

i mean if the url ends with `.clu` or `.lee` it should rewrite to `.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(clu|lee)$ $1.php
```

For reference, the [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) on `mod_rewrite` are quite thorough, and for a great intro to Regular Expressions, check [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) out.